# How to write a function that will clean a folder?

Tags: c, linux

I need write a function that will be clean a folder. I am already write some code

```
void cleandir(const char* path)
{
    struct dirent* file;
    struct stat filestat;
    DIR* fold = opendir(path);
    chdir(path);    //Open in this catalog
    while((file = readdir(fold)) != NULL)
    {
        if((strcmp(".", file->d_name) == 0) || (strcmp("..", file->d_name) == 0)) //Skip '.' and '..'
        continue;
    stat(file->d_name, &filestat);  //Put the info about file to the filestat struct
    if(S_ISDIR(filestat.st_mode) == 1)
    {
        //What to do if it's a folder
        //Recursion?
    }
    else if(S_ISREG(filestat.st_mode) == 1)
    {
        //What to do if it's a file
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.1. Kernel version is 4.15.0-50-generic.

Comment: What is your problem or question?

Answer (score 1):

To handle the directory, you could again call your `cleandir` recursively and pass the `path` appended with directory separator and the `file->d_name` as an argument. When the recursion returns use [remove](https://linux.die.net/man/3/remove) to delete the directory.

To delete the file you can use [unlink](https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink).

Answer (score 1):

Beware, entries in a directory are not limited to regular files and directories: you could have Unix domain sockets, symbolic links and *special* (device) files.

IMHO you should only test for directories, because a directory can only be removed when it is empty, so recursion is needed here (followed with a `rmdir` call) and all other entries for which you can just use `unlink`.

Comment: So, I appended an rmdir(file->d_name) and cleandir(file->d_name) into S_ISDIR, also I appended unlink(file->d_name) into S_ISREG. To clean all directory I need start the programm more than one time.